# Why is pygame.surface.get_view() failing only when the surface has been rotated?

Tags: python, pygame

Uploading an image to a surface and using the get_view() function works fine and i'm able to leverage the raw byte content of that function.  However, if I try to get_view() on a rotated surface it fails with the following: (Additional note it does not fail on even 90 degree increments).  "ValueError: the bytes are not contiguous" Below is the issue in simplified form:

### Python version 3.8.1

### Pygame version 1.9.6

### OS: Windows 10 Pro

```
import pygame as pg

Surf = pg.image.load('C:/TimW/Tmp_Images/Test3.png') # Works
Surf_View = Surf.get_view() # Works
Surf_New = pg.transform.rotate(Surf,10) #Works
Surf_New_View = Surf_New.get_view() #Works

x = Surf_New_View.raw  #Fails
print('done')
```

Note:  After further testing... some other rotation angles work as well I looped over 360 angles and about 17 worked or so.  I also tried 32 bit python and and several versions.  After further tracing I believe this is some low level math issues that I cannot get to.... anytime this contiguous error occurs there are also exceptions thrown in builtins….

Specifically "{'ArithmeticError': , 'AssertionError': , 'AttributeError': , 'BaseException': , 'BlockingIOError': , 'BrokenPipeError': , 'BufferError': , 'BytesWarning': , 'ChildProcessError': , 'ConnectionAbortedError': , 'ConnectionError': , 'ConnectionRefusedError': , 'ConnectionResetError': , 'DeprecationWarning': , ...}"

Comment: your code works for me without error - LInux Mint, Python 3.7, PyGame 1.9.6. Maybe you have problem in different place of code. OR it is problem only on your system. Always show full error message in question (not in comment)

Comment: BTW: there is good rule to use `lower_case_names` for variables, and `UpperCaseNames` only for classes - it helps to recognize class in code. See more: [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Comment: I forgot the offending line.... see the x =

Comment: FYI - I program in about 10 different languages including databases and while the style point is nice in Python i'm not a full time python developer so I use a style that I found most portable across the languages.

Comment: and that is not my code.... that was just for testing... I use a entirely different format in my code.... clsClass,   oObject, etc...

Comment: I can't help - all your code works without error on my Linux, and I don't have Windows. even `x =` doesn't give error.

Answer (score 0):

All this issue is resolved.  I have no idea why it makes a difference to the rotate/get_view functionality but when loading the image you must use the convert_alpha.  This is optional and not sure why it solves this problem but it does.

pg.image.load('C:/TimW/Tmp_Images/Test3.png').convert_alpha()